# Combine two Datatypes into new one(Path and String)

Tags: java, parameters, type-conversion

Maybe it's a stupid question but: Is it possible to combine two Datatypes like Path and String into a new one?

My actual problem is the following: I'm refactoring some code. Now I have a method which renames a file. But I've got four methods instead of only one, because the parameters are different:

```
public void copyFile(Path filesource, Path filedest) {
    try {
        Files.copy(filesource, filedest, REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}


public void copyFile(String filesource, Path filedest) {
    this.copyFile(getPathObjekt(filesource), filedest);
}


public void copyFile(Path filesource, String filedest) {
    this.copyFile(filesource, getPathObjekt(filedest));
}


public void copyFile(String filesource, String filedest) {
    this.copyFile(getPathObjekt(filesource), getPathObjekt(filedest));
}
```

So it would be nice to do something like this instead of using four methods:

```
public void(copyFile(StringPath filesource, StringPath filedest){

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but Java won't autobox the String/Path to the new entity - StringPath. Maybe you should leave the interface simple and let the user adopt to it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `java.io.File` class?

It already has constructors that can combine a path with a file name.

```
public void copyFile(File filesource, File filedest) {

}
```